# How do you properly write a question that contains follow-up questions?

Tags: punctuation, question-mark

For example if you were to write a question like: "Is this something that you would be interested in, and if so: when are you be available?"

How do you structure the sentence with regards to question marks and punctuation?

Answer (score 2):

"Is this something that you would be interested in, and if so, when are you be [sic] available?"

The correct punctuation to use is a comma after "if so". The general structure is-

> [question], and if so, [other question]?

Comment: Hi, thank you. So there is no situation in which you would use multiple question marks for these situations?

Comment: If you make two sentences, then you can use two question marks: "Is this something that you would be interested in? If so, when will you be available?"

Comment: Otherwise it sounds quite weird.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Is having two questions in one sentence, as in my original example, correct in the first place, or should it be avoided all together? Was that last sentence correct?

Comment: It sends the message across, but it sounds rather strange. I'd prefer the comma.

Comment: @Oscar You asked about "proper" writing. In casual and informal writing, there can be leeway to knowingly use punctuation in non-standard ways. I might string together question marks within a single sentence, without new capitalization: "Are you hungry? tired? busy?," or throw colons around recklessly. If you're not confident doing so, there's no harm in sticking to what is academically correct, which is the answer above. Note, there's nothing wrong with putting multiple questions into a single sentence as long as it's grammatical.